# What is the equivalent IDL rebin and congrid function in matlab?

Tags: matlab, idl-programming-language

I am trying to rebin a matrix to a larger size in matlab. In IDL you can always use rebin(matrix,dimension) to generate the new matrix. Is there any equivalent function in matlab, or do I have to manipulate the interp() function in matlab?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like imresize() does the job. It can resize a matrix to given dimension.